# Woocommerce Rest Api Categories problem

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api

/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories

My site has 10 main categories. But when I run the query, only 3 main categories and their subcategories are listed. Other categories don’t come up with what could be the problem?

Comment: does it only show categories which are assigned to posts/pages?

Comment: The product does not come in categories. only the first 3 categories and sub-categories are coming.

Comment: Have you asked this in a WooCommerce community or support? 3rd party plugin dev support is off-topic here and not in this stacks scope

Answer (score 0):

am_ is correct, rest API categories has `hide_empty` default to true.  change your request to the following:
`/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories?hide_empty=false`

[Source](https://v2.wp-api.org/reference/categories/)

Comment: unfortunately did not work

Answer (score 0):

Now check the below code. It will work.

```
$data = [
            'hide_empty' => true
        ];
$products = $woocommerce->get('products/categories',$data);
```

Comment: The original question was about fetching data from the REST API though, not in PHP code.